# Magento websites on subdomain while main site is already on subdomain

Tags: magento-1.9, websites, stores

I have a magento setup on a subdomain ( shop.mysite.com ) and now I want to add multiple sites and configure them on subdomain like uk.mysite.com and in.mysite.com.

Is it possible ?

I tried it but all websites/stores loading same products even if they have been added for another store.

Issue is different because my site (main site) is already on subdomain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multistore - Prevent product from having multiple urls](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9042/multistore-prevent-product-from-having-multiple-urls)

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between stores and websites. You can link products to websites, not to stores.

Creating a new store or store view makes it possible to create a custom Base URL. If you set this and have your server configured correctly, it should work.